# È stato o è stata?

Tags: verbs, gender, agreement

La frase

> Navigare è stato un'esperienza bellissima

è corretta?

O devo dire

> Navigare è stata un'esperienza bellissima

?

O sono corrette entrambe?

Grazie mille!

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE!

Comment: Per me suona meglio la seconda.

Answer (score 3):

Puoi trovare la risposta al tuo dubbio nell'[Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accordo-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/):

> Questa tendenza presenta tuttavia qualche oscillazione: frequente è, ad es., l’incertezza in frasi con verbo *essere*, con le quali il participio può essere concordato con il soggetto oppure con il nome del predicato o il complemento predicativo:
>
>
> (8) L’iscrizione di Toro a “modello 21” è stata un brutto colpo («Corriere della sera» 12 febbraio 2010)
>
>
> ma:
>
>
> (9) La Lauda Air Italia è stato un buon affare? («Corriere della sera» 22 febbraio 1995)
>
>
> Ancora:
>
>
> (10) La Somalia è stata un Paese piuttosto secolarizzato («Corriere della sera» 10 febbraio 2010)
>
>
> ma:
>
>
> (11) l’Italia è stato un Paese fondatore dell’Unione monetaria («Corriere della sera» 24 dicembre 1997)

Quindi, nel tuo esempio, puoi usare sia *è stato* (concordando il participio con il soggetto *navigare*) sia *è stata* (facendo l'accordo con il predicativo *un'esperienza bellissima*).

Comment: Ti ringrazio per l'aiuto che mi hai dato.

Comment: @AntoniaProcissi This is not a forum and the space for answers is reserved for them, not for comments or acknowledgments, so I converted your post to a comment to Charo's answer. Welcome again anyway.